# CQRS, Event sourcing and ids of created records

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Just started with CQRS and Event sourcing. Its a general novice question, for those who worked with CQRS.

Say, we have an event "userRegistration", where we should create Id for this created user? Should we write this Id to event data? How it is usually done when modeling CQRS?

Comment: Its a general novice question, for those who worked with CQRS,

Comment: Remember that event represent something that already happened so it should be named in past tense like "UserRegistered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will normally want to have the id in the event data.  Handlers that listen for UserRegistered events are likely to need to know which User you are eventing about.

Any sufficiently unique method of id generation will do.  But you get great benefit from methods where the id generation is deterministic; it gives your system another way to recognize duplicated messages

Using a named UUID is a possible answer here, deterministic, but with a sufficiently minuscule collision frequency that you are unlikely to run into problems.

For instance, if the RegisterUser command has a unique identifier (useful, because it gives you another way to recognize duplicates), then you can use that identifier to deterministically generate a new identifier for the User.